# I need to apply Aggregator Mediator in WSO2 Integration Studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-esb

I need to apply Aggregator Mediator in WSO2 Integration Studio. An example or a reference to the example will suffice. I see examples in WSO2 documentation [https://docs.wso2.com/display/IntegrationPatterns/Aggregator] but they are for the portal. I need to do it in WSO2 Integration Studio.

Also any guide to distinguish the use of Integration Studio and the portal(Enterprise Integrator Carbon Server) will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following blogs

- https://medium.com/think-integration/how-to-train-your-micro-integrator-b8c28cadca00
- https://medium.com/think-integration/the-love-story-of-integration-studio-and-micro-integrator-7e10a8012f7f
- https://medium.com/think-integration/life-of-mi-how-an-esb-went-on-to-serve-microservices-9bb4faed5588

Also have a look at the documentation. https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/aggregate-Mediator/